# Does China pay for damages caused by deorbiting space junk?

Tags: debris, china, deorbit, liability

When China launches a big rocket, they apparently don't control the deorbit and there are large enough pieces to strike the surface and even cause damage to buildings, as happened in the Ivory Coast last year.

Because the Earth's surface is mostly ocean, the debris will most likely land there (not good for marine life in the way!), as with today's debris landing in the Indian ocean.  However, the uncontrolled deorbit seems to be designed in as a feature, not a bug, perhaps due to lack of liability for any associated damages.

If debris from such a rocket were to strike my home, car, kid, boat, passenger-aircraft-in-flight, etc., is there a claims process by which the Chinese launch authority will pay for those damages?  (Assume there is no insurance held by the owner which would cover such damages, as the probability of any specific individual being affected in that way is very low.)

Comment: This might have been asked in a different form before, but I'm not sure. But since your question is so much more scenario and country-specific, I think it needs an answer of its own. Btw the Planetary Society just published this a few days ago: [This Is What Legally Happens If An Uncontrolled Rocket Damages Something](https://www.planetary.org/articles/uncontrolled-reentry-rocket-damage-space-lawyers-explain)

Comment: If a piece of space debris was to strike your home, I imagine its value on ebay would cover the damages.

Comment: When Kosmos 954 had an uncontrolled re-entry over Norther Canada, *carrying a functioning nuclear reactor* with 50 kg of U-235, the subsequent cleanup ran up a bill of CDollars 6 M;  the Soviets paid CDollars  3 M   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosmos_954

Comment: This is going to happen a lot more often because CZ-5 is one-and-a-half stage to LEO, so the gigantic core stage (1st stage) will reach LEO and fly for a few days and eventually come down uncontrolled. I wish they would at least blow up the rocket into pieces shortly before or during reentry (maybe they are already doing that) to make sure nothing heavy reaches the ground. But CZ-5's main engine is relatively light and small, so no big pieces are hitting the ground to begin with, after all.

Comment: Duplicate of this question? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/uncontrolled-rocket-re-entry-kills-my-dog-what-are-the-legal-consequences

Comment: @user2705196 That's more about the general legal basis - and while yes, the Outer Space Treaty citation in the accepted answer is useful and relevant, the gist of the answer is that it's up to the launching state to voluntarily cover costs, or the landing country's *government* to pursue international negotiations (which could be put up against other unrelated issues).  It doesn't answer this question about if China actually does cover costs (incl. in recent history) or has a claims process in place.